# .htaccess if path (folder) doesn't exist request another path

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, path

By adding the language to my website i'm facing a problem. 
Becouse i don't want to change all my urls from all my templates but i want to keep the language into my url i need to modyfy the .htaccess .

Basicly the problem is as folows: - To keep the language in url i have to change the site url:
ex:

without language: http://www.mysite.com/some/other/vars   SITE_URL : http://www.mysite.com

with language: http://www.mysite.com/cn/some/other/vars  changed SITE_URL : http://www.mysite.com/cn

when i request for css file SITE_URL/my_style/style.css , obiously the css will not be found in 2'nd case becouse is not in the folder cn/

How i can modyfy the .htaccess to change the requested path if the path is :

http://www.mysite.com/cn

http://www.mysite.com/es

http://www.mysite.com/fr

Originaly htaccess content is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Options All -Indexes 
Options All -Indexes 
Options All -Indexes
```

Thanks..it should be simple...but i can't do it since 2 hours.

**EDIT:**

All i want is: 
If a request is made at: www.mysite.com/cn/any/thing/else/style.css (in this case css file will not exist), make the request at: www.mysite.com/any/thing/else/style.css

Was a long day with no progress ...haha. it happends.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to fix the issue by requesting correct url! That just would be right.

However this should work

```
RewriteRule ^(cn|es|fr)/my_style/(.+)$ /my_style/$2 [L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me (i got 404)...i found this link : http://www.syahzul.com/blogs/item/how-to-rewrite-your-assets-file-location-with-htaccess . There is an good example. I tried but still not working

Comment: Did you put that in next line just after `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: yes. i added this: RewriteRule ^(cn|es|fr)/templates/css/frontend/(.+)$ /templates/css/frontend/$2 [L] . in my case the css file is in site.com/templates/css/frontend/style.css the cn/ folder doesn't exist, is virtual. browser tries to get the css from site.com/cn/templates/css/frontend/style.css .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the htaccess files that you have in your `cn/es/fr` folders, preferably before any rules that you may have there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

This should make it so a request for `/my_style/style.css` from within the `cn` folder will serve the one from the document root.